# Turn angular functions in javascript script in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have some sliders and checkboxes that I want to use with same functionality both in my app, as well as web. In my app I use Angular 2 and  have html and ts file that works together, obviously. These sliders and checkboxes look like this in those files:

HTML:

```
<label for="objectScale">Scale</label>
<input #objectScaleSlider id="objectScale" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="1" (input)="onObjectScaleChange($event.target.value)"/>

<label for="showTags">Show_marks</label>
<input #showMarksCheckBox id="showMarks" type="checkbox" (change)="onMarksVisibileChange($event.target.checked)" checked="checked"/>
```

Level_opacity

```
<label for="showlevel">Show_level</label>
<input #showLevelCheckBox id="showLevel" type="checkbox" (change)="onShowLevelChange($event.target.checked)" checked="checked"/>
```

as for TS related to these:

```
onObjectScaleChange(value : string) {
    this.sceneManager.onChangeScale(parseFloat(value));
}
onTagsVisibileChange(value) {
    this.sceneManager.showObject = value;
    this.sceneManager.update();
}
onLevelOpacityChange(value) {
    this.sceneManager.levelOpacity = value;
}

onShowLevelChange(value) {
    this.sceneManager.showLevel = value;
}
```

I managed to set these labels and input in different html file that I use for web tab that opens on click, but don't know how can I make them functional like it works in relation html-ts file in angular.

My web html looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container preview">
    <div class="design-menu-header" onclick="onActiveViewChange('2d')">2D</div>
    <div class="design-menu-header" onclick="onActiveViewChange('3d')">3D</div>

    <div id="design-2d-container" class="design-svg">
        <div class="design-internal">
            <label for="objectScale">Scale</label>
            <input #objectScaleSlider id="objectScale" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="1" (input)="onObjectScaleChange($event.target.value)"/>

            <label for="showObject">Show object</label>
            <input #showObejctCheckBox id="showObjects" type="checkbox" (change)="onTagsVisibileChange($event.target.checked)" checked="checked"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="design-container" class="design-weee" style="display:none">
        <div class="design-internal">
            <label for="levelOpacity">Level opacity</label>
            <input #levelOpacitySlider id="levelOpacity" type="range" min="0.1" max="0.8" step="0.1" value="0.8" (input)="onLevelOpacityChange($event.target.value)"/>
            <label for="showLevel">Show level</label>
            <input #showLevelCheckBox id="showLevel" type="checkbox" checked="checked" (change)="onShowLevelChange($event.target.checked)" checked="checked"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var scene2dManager, scene3dManager;
    function onObjectScaleChange(value) {
        this.sceneManager.onChangeScale(parseFloat(value));
    }
    function onTagsVisibileChange(value) {
        this.sceneManager.showElement = value;
        this.sceneManager.update();
    }
    function onLevelOpacityChange(value) {
        this.sceneManager.levelOpacity = value;
    }
    function onShowLevelChange(value) {
        this.sceneManager.showLevel = value;
    }
</script>
```

Any help on this to work in web and javascript same as in html-ts in angular? Thanks

Comment: Well if you are not using angular `(change)="..."` is not the way you add events... and there is no $event

Comment: @epascarello he did add `$event` so that part of his code is correct ...